# Login through unprotected network

Tags: security, hash, salt, nonce

We are designing an API endpoint for clients to use to log into our service. However, I do have a question about how to be sure that the user's password is protected while using an unprotected network.

After thinking about this issue, we concluded that we can modify our application to request a nonce before trying to log in [two requests per each login attempts] and then hash the user's password before actually trying to send it over the network. This solves the problem with sending user password through the unprotected network and as a side bonus we can check the nonce and invalidate it to prevent any later reply attacks.

However for this to work, I didn't find any way to be able to use a Salt in the hashing mechanism as if we do, the user can not generate the right hash or we need to send the Salt to the user.

What I have now in my mind is as follows:

1. Application asks for a one-time nonce [time limited and randomly generated]
2. Application hash the user password: [using the nonce in the process]

`sha1(sha1([password]) + [nonce])`

3. Application send the authentication request with username, hashed pass and hashed nonce to get a JWT token
4. Web server validates the nonce and then the provided password based on the provided username and if successful sends a token to the client so it can use other endpoints.

`[resquestHashedPassword] == sha1([dbHashedPassword] + [nonce])`

5. The client continues to work with other parts of the service using the provided JWT.

Is there a way that I can keep the user's password secure while being able to use hashing salt on the server side data storage?

In a nutshell, this is a question about how to use both "[Nonce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce)" as part of authentication requests and "[Salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography))" for password storage.

*** EDIT 1 ***

Just adding some clarifications:

1. I know that we can use HTTPS to encrypt the data in transmission (and we sure do), however, HTTPS is not impenetrable. So not an actual answer to the question.
2. I am not trying to make my own crypto. I am merely trying to use other well-defined solutions like sending a nonce and keeping a salt next to password. However, I can't find a way to do both.
3. I am aware of other forms of attack. However, the question is about the security of the user's password and not about the application/service security. If I don't need the password in cleartext, why should I send it over the network? Security of the network is another issue that the question is not concerned with.
4. `SHA1` is only an example.

*** EDIT 2 ***

What do you think about using the user's username (in our case it is their phone number, so 10 digits, while 4 of them are not actually random) as the salt? It sure has a very little entropy comparing to a random salt, but this is the only way I found so far that enables me to use both methods. Or is it more secure to rely on HTTPS to be perfect and instead abandon the idea of using "Nonce" in the hash function altogether?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, [don't roll your own crypto](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own).

Second, your system is still vulnerable to many kinds of attacks, such as man-in-the-middle, eavsdropping, phishing, and session hijacking. If a hacker would have had access to the password, he would also have access to the hash, and could intercept it and use it himself. He will also be able to see the response and steal whatever session key is generated, then impersonate the client. And in all scenarios he'll be able to view whatever the content is that you're trying to secure.

The proper way to secure this is with SSL/TLS. Once the secure tunnel is established you can pass the credentials "in the clear," relying on the encryption offered by HTTPS.

Comment: I understand other forms of attack in which an attacker can send invalid data to our servers with the stolen session key or the token. However, I am more concerned about the user's password instead of security of the service.

Comment: Yep. The hacker can also impersonate the server and provide whatever nonce he wants, even the same one over and over to every user, then see his choice of attack (dictionary, rainbow) on the hashes. Your scheme is worthless without authentication and encryption.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm assuming by "application requests" and "API endpoint" means we're looking at messages in separate connections like HTTP, rather than a single bidirectional connection with own protocol.)

There's a number of problems with the scheme you propose:

1. Weak hash in the database: you need to store `sha1(password)` on the server side for this to work and this is not strong enough. You can fix this by storing something using proper PBKDF with a salt and sending salt along with the nonce to the client.
2. Weak password on the wire. SHA1 is REALLY fast. SHA1 twice + salt is not much better. It will prevent rainbow table attacks, but dictionary attacks 
   against it are still trivial.
3. Replay attack still possible. You can MITM this connection and replace the request contents with whatever you want, preserving only the authentication. You need to sign the hash of authentication along with any request data and relevant headers.
4. You don't seem to tie your requests in any way to the time. The attacker can setup a proxy which saves the nonces, the response and drops the connection before transmitting the response back. If you don't include a signed timestamp in the requests, the attacker now has a stash of authentication hashes / requests they can use in the future.

Recommendation: see the authentication used in other places, like [AWS v4](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html).

At the minimum, I'd change your scheme to:

1. Request nounce + password salt, which is granted for the specific user, for time range from now to 5 seconds later
2. Send a request, which includes:

   - current time
   - username
   - request content/headers
   - signature for `HMAC(k, list_of(nonce, time, username, request data))`
   - (where `k` is `PBKDF(password, salt)`)

This still doesn't change the fact that your database is now the database of plaintext passwords effectively, which is a really bad idea. Authenticating with a plaintext password over HTTPS and getting a temporary token for signing the requests would be a *much* better solution.

Comment: Yes, this is true, I meant separate HTTP requests. 1, 2: Totaly right, SHA1 was just an example. 3: I do sign the user password with the nonce (as well as sending it along), so changing it with a new one still results in rejection of the request. 4: How having a lot of nonces makes this a problem? They can have as much as they want, however, I cant think of a way that they can misuse this data to decrypt user's pass. It is important to add that nonces are random (reasonably) and obviously limiting them to time is what we should do. But I understand that it wasn't in the text of the question.

Comment: @SoroushFalahati For 3, I mean changing the request, not the authentication. For example you send `["your_user","correct_auth_hash","do_this_thing"]` and I change it in flight to `["your_user","correct_auth_hash","delete_the_database"]`.

For 4, I don't mean you can decrypt the password. If you don't bind the auth hash to the time, I can just store the right auth hashes for later use - I don't need to know the user password anymore.

Comment: After clearing that parts, now, is this reasonably safe to send the salt to the user? One might be able to extract all salts (as we didn't finish the authentication process yet [first request])

Comment: @SoroushFalahati I added a recommendation what needs to be changed if you really want to do this, but this is still a bad idea. Oauth2 and other schemes exist for a reason - use them if you can.

Comment: Thanks, very good information. The use of time in the request made me remember about the client nonce. You did suggest it based on that idea, right? Also, I edited the question to include the fact that the whole conversation is about the login method and the rest of application actually do use tokens. We are just overly sensitive about that first request.

Answer (score 1):

I do have a suggestion to make , if you want to factor in that someone is able to penetrate HTTPS at some point of time , then i would recommend that a user specific symmetric key be provisioned once and it be used to encrypt the user credentials + time-stamp before it is send over the wire .

For provisioning the symmetric key on the Fly DSKPP can be used https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6063

DSKPP will need the user to enter a passphrase during the key provisioning stage , the passphrase can be pre-generated and stored against the user in the server database and can be shared securely with the user through other channel like SMS / email etc .

But this will require lot of work to be done... you need to factor in the RISK against the cost.